# Qt и Excel. Не собирается проект

Tags: linux, windows, qt, excel, qt5

Необходимо работать с .xlsx файлами через Qt 5.7 с помощью модуля QtXlsx. Проект с данным модулем вроде собирается, но при компиляции выдает вот что:

```
D:\Qt\Projects\TryExcel\qtexcel\src\xlsx\xlsxzipreader.cpp:51: ошибка: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QVector<QZipReader::FileInfo>'
 QList<QZipReader::FileInfo> allFiles = m_reader->fileInfoList();
                                                               ^
D:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:1139: In file included from ..\..\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore/qglobal.h:1139:0,
D:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore\QtGlobal:1: from ..\..\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore/QtGlobal:1,
D:\Qt\Projects\TryExcel\qtexcel\src\xlsx\xlsxglobal.h:27: from ..\TryExcel\qtexcel\src\xlsx\xlsxglobal.h:27,
D:\Qt\Projects\TryExcel\qtexcel\src\xlsx\xlsxzipreader_p.h:40: from ..\TryExcel\qtexcel\src\xlsx\xlsxzipreader_p.h:40,
D:\Qt\Projects\TryExcel\qtexcel\src\xlsx\xlsxzipreader.cpp:26: from ..\TryExcel\qtexcel\src\xlsx\xlsxzipreader.cpp:26:
D:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore\qtypeinfo.h:189: declaration of 'class QVector<QZipReader::FileInfo>'
D:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore\qtypeinfo.h:189: declaration of 'class QVector<QZipReader::FileInfo>'
Q_DECLARE_MOVABLE_CONTAINER(QVector);
                            ^
```

Собирал под Qt 5.7.1 на Win 7 x64 с компилятором mingw и на ubuntu 16.04 с GCC. Может у кого-нибудь такая же проблема была, подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только задал вопрос и тут же нашел решение сам. Необходимо было добавить в xlsxzipreader.cpp заголовочный файл QVector и заменить в строке с ошибкой QList на QVector.